# Change value of variables for certain months of an R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, tidyverse, lubridate

I would like to change the values of `Obs` and `Sim` to `-1.23` when `Month =< 2 & Month >= 11`. Seems something simple but am not coming up with any solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                  Ob = runif(1095,1,5), Sim = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
        separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"))
```

Comment: You cannot have Month value <= 2 as well as >= 11 at the same time. I think the `&` (AND) should be `|` (OR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert `Month` to numeric so that you can compare the values. Next you can change the values of `Ob` and `Sim` columns to constant when `Month <= 2` OR  `>= 11`.

```
DF$Month <- as.numeric(DF$Month)
DF[DF$Month <= 2 |  DF$Month >= 11, c('Ob', 'Sim')] <- -1.23
```

Or using `%in%` :

```
DF[DF$Month %in% c(1,2,11,12), c('Ob', 'Sim')] <- -1.23
```

---

If you want to use `dplyr` you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- DF %>% 
       mutate(across(c(Ob, Sim), ~replace(., Month %in% c(1, 2, 11, 12), -1.23)))
```

Comment: How about something like using `Month %in% c(1,2,11,12)` and change the values? Can we change the values for these months without going out of the pipe `(%>%)` operator?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues to resolve. One is to make Month and Date numeric so you can use equal and greater/less than operators on them. Once you have that, use `case_when` to execute your replacement logic. The third issue is that `=<` is not a valid function. You should use `<=`. Finally, `Month <= 2 & Month >= 11` will return 0 rows because no row can return TRUE for both clauses. I used a different criterion in my example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

DF <- tibble(Date = seq(ymd("2001-01-01"), to = ymd("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
             Ob = runif(1095,1,5),
             Sim = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date),
         Month = month(Date),
         Day = mday(Date))

DF %>% 
  mutate(Ob = case_when(Month <= 10 & Month >= 6 ~ -1.23,
                        TRUE ~ Ob),
         Sim = case_when(Month <= 10 & Month >= 6 ~ -1.23,
                        TRUE ~ Sim)) %>% 
  filter(Month <= 10 & Month >= 6)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Date          Ob   Sim  Year Month   Day
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 2001-06-01 -1.23 -1.23  2001     6     1
2 2001-06-02 -1.23 -1.23  2001     6     2
3 2001-06-03 -1.23 -1.23  2001     6     3
4 2001-06-04 -1.23 -1.23  2001     6     4
5 2001-06-05 -1.23 -1.23  2001     6     5
6 2001-06-06 -1.23 -1.23  2001     6     6
```